# How to set up a proxy on my server

Tags: proxy

How can I set up a proxy on my server? I don't mean a Glype proxy where there is an web form in which you enter a URL. What I mean is something like one [that's listed here](http://spys.ru/), where you can enter IP address and port.

How do I set up my server for this?

I need this so my PHP script on another server can connect through that server like `$proxy = 192.155....:80` and then use that to handle GET and POST requests.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is SQUID ( http://www.squid-cache.org ) which is most popular software used for proxies. But in order to setup a proxy you will need a VPS - that means direct access to the server and rights to install and configure software such as SQUID.
Once you install SQUID, here's a short simple how to how to configure it as a transparent proxy: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-setup-transparent-proxy-squid-howto.html

Comment: so i would need ssh access, no way to do this without i suppose?

Comment: Yes. This is because PHP currently operates for Apache. Any PHP scripted run through Apache probably cannot be a server, because there is such thing as a time limit for PHP scripts. Once it is hit, the script is killed by server. So, the best thing you could achieve by writing a PHP proxy server is similar to TorrentFlux - the script would work only for a limited time. Apart from this, I see no reason why it shouldn't be possible to write a PHP proxy server.